# not able to run job in batch

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2009

```
static void Job47(Args _args)
{
str                                  path,stx;
TreeNodeIterator                     iter;
TreeNode                             treeNode, treeNodeToRelease;
Map                                  dictMenuDisplay;
FormName                             formName;
MenuItemName                         menuItemName;
container                            conMenu;
int                                  i,n;
    ;

   for (n=1;n<=1;n++)
   {
    info::messageWinAddLine(strfmt("iter:%1",n));
    path            ="Menu Items\\Display";
    dictMenuDisplay = new Map(Types::String,Types::Container);
    treenode        = Treenode::findNode(path);
    iter            = treenode.AOTiterator();
    treenode        = iter.next();

    while (treenode)
      {
        formName     = treenode.AOTgetProperty("Object");
        menuItemName = treenode.AOTname();

       if (dictMenuDisplay.exists(formName))
        {
         conMenu = dictMenuDisplay.lookup(formName);
         conMenu = conIns(conMenu,conlen(conMenu)+1,menuItemName);
         dictMenuDisplay.insert(formName,conMenu);
         }

       else
         dictMenuDisplay.insert(formName,[menuItemName]);
         treenode = iter.next();
    }  
 }
}
```

When I run the above job in batch it shows the following error "The server side impersonated(RunAs) session tried to invoke a method available for client-side processing only" and points to the line
    info::messageWinAddLine(strfmt("iter:%1",n));
I have tried putting false in the method runsImpersonated() in class RunbaseBatch. But doesnt seems to work either.

I am new to AX2009 so dont really understand what it means to running job in client or in server, kindly lead me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove the modification to the RunBaseBatch class. That method is mean to be overridden in any classes extending that class (inheritance). Take a look at the class "Tutorial_RunbaseBatch" for insight on how the RunBaseBatch pattern can be achieved.

Now, also consider that when you run x++ code, it can be run either client-side or server-side. You can have methods locked for which side you allow the code to run. The GLobal::info-method can run both client- and server-side.
When you activate a batch to run a class (not a job), a class extending RunBaseBatch, then the Batch Framework will run the class server side according to your settings. Your code should then be independent of client-side, meaning there can not be any line of code that requires access to client-side. WinAPI::moveFile is an example.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Hi Skaue thanks for the quick response. Can you explain  if is there any advantage of running a job or a class server-side or client-side. How come i would know that what line of code would be access server-side or client-side. In my job the line info::messageWinAddLine(strfmt("iter:%1",n)); is it in the client-side?

Comment: When you interactively run a job within the client, you explicitly run it from client-side. You can active breakpoints and the debugger will show when code is running either client side or server side. They show this by having a icon in the call stack. 
Having a class that can run as a batch might be an advantage if that ever is a feature the customer wants. Being able to export data for instance as a nightly batch job is normal. It all depends on what your class is for.

Comment: silly question though..how would i know what is my class for? can you explain a little bit? In my job the line info::messageWinAddLine(strfmt("iter:%1",n)); is it in the client-side or server? thanks afgain for the quick response.

Comment: you can tag methods with modifiers for client or server:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa891619.aspx

Classes has a meta property on them called RunOn where the options are CalledFrom/Client/Server. In addition, any MenuItems for Action (which are classes) have also the ability to define "RunOn".

If you want to know if the info-method in your code is run on client or server, simply add a breakpoint on that line and look at the icon in the callstack. A small computer indicates client, a server-looking icon indicates server.

oh, and there are no silly questions, just dumb answers

Comment: i really appreciate your effort. Thanks a lot for your comments i ilike it...In case i have anything more to ask regarding the same i will surely write it down here . Thanks again.

Comment: hey Skaue 1 last question. Suppose i have a job which runs in a server and a line in job needs to run on client-side, can i achive this? Cause when I run the method WeekofYear in Global class in batch, it is not executed(cause it makes calls to WINApi class methods which can only run on client.) Please help.

Comment: Yea. It's the firstDayOfWeek-method that tries to load this from the system. To bad they didn't use .Net for that instead. If you can use ISO-8601, then I'd prefer to use the wkOfYr-method instead. If your code is to run serverside for sure, then you could also use the .Net libraries for this. Just make sure to assert the CLR permissions for TWC. Your problem is a perfect example of how Batch can break when there is a dependency to WinAPI.

Comment: Can u write in a bit detail, i tried to use the .net libraries but that too doesnt seem to work(calls client-side too.

Comment: The .Net libraries will run on the "side" you determine in advance. As already mentioned you can tag classes and methods and even menuitems to run server side only. Any particular reason you can't use wkOfYr()?

Comment: yes all i am trying to do is run WeekOfyear in Batch and it throws an error "The server side impersonated(RunAs) session tried to invoke a method available for client-side processing only". I want to use .net lib or any dummy classes or methods to get through the issue, just frustrated nt able to find a way out :(

Comment: And how to use the .net lib here and to assert the CLR permissions for TWC? Gosh am so dumb..

Comment: wkOfYr() and WeekOfYear are two different methods. The first one assumes ISO-8601, and if you can use that one, you won't get the impersonation error. 
TWC stands for Trust Worthy Computing. Before you run code that requires interoperability with .Net (CLR), you should assert you have the proper access for this. Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa605505.aspx

Comment: thanks again for the prompt reply, (im assuming iso-8601)well unfortunately wkOfYr() method is nt there in my Global class(could u send me the code).For the time being you im trying to create appropriate methods in the WinAPIServer class making sure that the relavent code runs in server only. I'll also try using .net lib later. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its working! i have customised my WinAPIserver with the appropriate methods and also made use of the assert() method. Now i shall try to gain the same using the .net lib(how to use the .net lib in x++ could you suggest any docs with example?). Thanks a tonn for your assistance once again :)

Comment: Yeah U were right WkOfYr() too runs on server. Its working fine too. Could you get some idea or any example regarding achieving the same using .net Libraries, Please.

Comment: There are douzens of examples out there: http://www.google.no/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=get+week+of+year+c%23

The thing you have to remember though, is you will have to access the .Net libraries with full namespaces. Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc598160.aspx